# Camel Route, invalid content was found starting with element "dataFormats"

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am having an issue with my camel route and it not recognizing my "dataFormats" tag. I think I may have something wrong with my namespaces but I am not sure exactly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My error is the following:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:2.10.4:run (default-cli) on project ExactTargetSample: null: MojoExecutionException: InvocationTargetException: Line 52 in XML document from file [C:\EclipseWorkspaces\EclipseWorkSpaceCurrent\ApacheCamel\target\classes\META-INF\spring\camel-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 20; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '**dataFormats**'. One of '{"http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":avro, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":beanio, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":bindy, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":castor, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":crypto, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":csv, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":custom, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":flatpack, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":gzip, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":hl7, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":jaxb, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":jibx, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":json, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":protobuf, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":rss, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":secureXML, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":serialization, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":soapjaxb, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":string, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":syslog, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":tidyMarkup, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":xmlBeans, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":xmljson, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":xstream, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":pgp, "http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring":zip}' is expected. -> [Help 1]

---

And a copy of my route can be found below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

 <!-- load properties --> 

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="file:backend.properties" /> 
</bean>
<bean id="properties" class="org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent">
    <property name="location" value="file:backend.properties" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?useLocalHost=true" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="8" /> 
    <property name="maximumActive" value="500" /> 
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" /> 
    <property name="transacted" value="false" /> 
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" /> 
</bean>

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" /> 
</bean>

<!-- Custom Loaded Beans -->

<bean id="TriggeredSendBean" class="com.backend.trigger.ClientTest"/>

 <!-- camel configuration --> 

<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <dataFormats>
        <json id="WelcomeEmail" library="Jackson" unmarshalTypeName="com.testObjects.EnrollResponse" />
     <dataFormats>

    <camel:route id="genericMessageHandler" streamCache="true">
    <from uri="activemq:topic:Test.Central" /> 
    <unmarshal ref="WelcomeEmail" /> 

    <to uri = "bean:TriggeredSendBean?method=setup" /> 
    <to uri = "bean:TriggeredSendBean?method=addSubscriberAllList" />
    <to uri = "bean:TriggeredSendBean?method=sendWelcomeEmail" />

    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good. May be you missed to add the camel-jackson dependency to your pom. Just a guess !

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Turns out that I forgot to put "camel" in front of my dataFormats, because I declared that in the namespace declarations. Completely skipped over that. Thanks for the help though!